# Laravel 5.4 Search for Post District Wildcard

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a postcode area table with the following structure:

```
|id   |post_district   | search        |local_authority   |gov_region   |country |
|31   |BA22            |BA22, BA2*, BA*|South Somerset    |South West   |England |
|32   |BA9             |BA9, BA*       |South Somerset    |South West   |England |
```

(all columns are of type string). The search column contains possible wildcard variations of the postcode.

I'm having issue creating a function that will pass in a code (possibly with wildcard, hence search) and returning all rows that match.

Something like the following :

```
 function SearchPostDistrict($code){
    return DB::table('postcodes_area')->where($code, is_substring($this))->get() //PSEUDO-CODE
 }
```

This would be simpler if I could have an array column type and simply have a where clause

```
->whereIn($code, 'search')
```

Is it possible in laravel 5.4 to have some sort of sophisticated query builder function like this?

Alternatively, I could return all of the Postcode Areas (of which there are 2451 records). Then loop through each checking if $code is a substring of the records search variable, and build a collection myself that I return.

Would this be a performance problem? This is a side to Laravel I know little about. How would this effect things for me?

**Solution:**
I believe I can use

```
function SearchPostDistrict($code){
    return DB::table('postcodes_area')->where('search', 'LIKE', '%'.$code.'%')->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find specific posts by the following any filter:

```
$posts = Post::all(); //Send all posts
$posts = Post::where('title','Post Two')->get(); //get title as mentioned
$posts = DB::select('Select * from posts'); //If you want write query then "use DB;" at top of the Controller file
$posts = Post::orderBy('title','desc')->take(1)->get(); // Get one post
$posts = Post::orderBy('title','desc')->get();
```

Comment: You can use any of the above function to get spesific posts in LARAVEL